# How can I write a function which takes an array as argument and it returns a new array with all values of the original array but in reverse order

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting, arraylist

I just started a full-stack web development Bootcamp, because is something that I liked and I really wanted to learn and I needed some guidelines, browsing through the internet on my own was a bit confusing. But, I don't really have lots of money so, is the cheapest Bootcamp I could find, aka, everything prerecorded, and not really a lot of personal attention from the teachers. So, that is why I'm here. With CSS and HTML, I really got no problems but javascript is a bit confusing, know I'm working with really simple functions but I'm unable to make them work. I have to write a function that takes an array, and from that array, it creates a new one but in reverse order. I tried this

```js
function takeAll(array){
    var newArray = [array.reverse()];
    console.log(newArray)
    return newArray;
}
```

But I get this error and I don't know how to solve it. `VM97:2 Uncaught TypeError: array.reverse is not a function at takeAll (<anonymous>:2:27) at <anonymous>:1:1`

I think the reverse function is already prebuilt, I don't know why do I get that.

Comment: Is `array` really an array? Try to do `console.log( array )` at the beginning of your function

Comment: Please specify your parameter to `takeAll()` as well.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't giving an array to the function, solved, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your function should work, if you change the line

```
[array.reverse()]
```

to

```
array.reverse()
```

Otherwise, you'll end up with an output like [[3,2,1]] (an array of arrays).

```js
function takeAll(array) {
    console.log("takeAll: IsArray:", Array.isArray(array));
    return array.reverse();
}

const input = [1,2,3];
console.log('Input:', input);
console.log('Output:', takeAll(input));
```

Comment: Thanks Terry! I just tried that too and I get a similar error "Uncaught TypeError: array.reverse is not a function at takeAll (<anonymous>:2:26) at <anonymous>:1:1 " should I write the reverse function inside the other function?

Comment: I would suggest logging console.log("IsArray:", Array.isArray(array)) in your function takeAll, Array.reverse() should be supported by almost all browsers / JS implementations. This log line will tell you if your input is an array or not.

Answer (score 1):

`reverse()` will return an array. You dont need to add [] there.

```js
function takeAll(array){
    var newArray = array.reverse();
    console.log(newArray)
    return newArray;
}

takeAll([1,3,4,5]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried that but I got a similar error "Uncaught TypeError: array.reverse is not a function at takeAll (<anonymous>:2:26) at <anonymous>:1:1
" should I write the reverse function inside the other function?

Comment: @The_Real_Gabo Are you passing array as an argument to the takeAll function? Can you post your input here?

Comment: Oh freak, such dumb mistakes! I was passing an array without "[ ]" so, no array at all, just a lot of integers/arguments. Now it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you mark here questions as solved?

Comment: @The_Real_Gabo glad it worked. Keep learning!!

Comment: There is  tick under up/down arrows to accept answer.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem I wasn't passing an array. My bad haha, thanks, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your function you are returning an array which contains another array, I don't think this is really what you want.

The code you need is the following :

```html
function takeAll(array) { 
  return array.reverse() 
}
```

Make sure you pass an array in your function.

Comment: Thanks Imiscoli! I just tried that too and I get a similar error "Uncaught TypeError: array.reverse is not a function at takeAll (<anonymous>:2:26) at <anonymous>:1:1 " should I write the reverse function inside the other function?

Comment: What browser are you using to execute your code? Could you show me some pictures of the error and how are you invoking the function?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the square brackets from `[array.reverse()]` and it should work.

You could also write your own function (sorry my code is really bad) :

```
function takeAll(ar) {
    let newAr = new Array(ar.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        newAr[i] = ar[(ar.length - 1) - i];
    }
    console.log(newAr);
    return newAr;
}
```

What that does is just takes the input array, makes a new array of the same length and assign's the values of the initial array to the new array in reverse order.

Sorry if this is not a sufficient answer.